# Firebase cloud messaging not working in background

Tags: android, firebase, api, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send push notifications to my app. But the app is not receiving notifications if it is in background. I am using Firebase cloud messaging service.

here is the onMessageReceived method:

```
 @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        String body = data.get("body");
        String title = data.get("title");
        String id = data.get("android_channel_id");
        int priority = remoteMessage.getPriority();


        final NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

 Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), id)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText(body)
                        .setPriority(priority)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setStyle(new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle())
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.aajevan_logo))

                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .build();

                notificationManager.notify(200, notification);


 @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String s) {
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {

                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d("*******FAILED", task.getException().getMessage());
                            return;
                        }

                        String token = task.getResult().getToken();
                        Log.d("/**MY TOKEN", token);
                    }
                });
    }
```

When the app is in foreground or background there is no problem. But it does not work if I kill my app. If I open the app once then I am receiving all my notifications at once.

Comment: Have you added Firebase Service in your Manifest?

Comment: So what is the problem: "the app is not receiving notifications if it is in background" or "it does not work if I kill my app"? Background and killed are two different states.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu Yes. it does not work if I kill my app in the background

Comment: @GouseMohiddin Yes I did

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are 2 types of messages(notifications and data). Firebase Console sends notification messages. When you send these type of messages the firebase will handle them automatically when your application is closed or in background (not killed). check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options) for more info about notification messages and data messages.

Also, a killed application is an application that a user force stopped it or it crashed due to a bug or the Operating System decided to kill it (battery management). A killed application will not receive any kind of notifications.